# spring-cloud-config client not getting refreshed on property change

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I get my spring-boot application (client) to refresh it's properties - which are coming from spring-cloud-config stand alone Server? I've annotated @RefreshScope, added config in bootstrap.yml for spring.cloud.config.uri and spring.application.name I can see server is able to get the config using it's HTTP end-pt and also Client gets the config using spring-boot /manage/env end-pt. It's just that if I commit a property change to git, it is not changing in my Client App.